# How to disable navigation bar for my android app

Tags: android, navigationbar, android-homebutton, disabled-control, recent-screens

I want to disable navigationbar for my android app.
When my application open home button and recent app button disable.

How can I disable button when app is running?

Like pattern lock app, in this app when open lock screen disable all button.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag in your activity's onResume method.

This should help:
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Edit:

So it looks like you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983295/6176618

This this isn't officially supported and the workaround provided here is an obvious hack but it should serve your purposes.

Comment: but it's only hide navigationbar. when i touch on screen navigationbar work automatically.

Comment: Ahh, it sounds like you want the 'Sticky Immersion' feature? http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: But how can i disable navigationbar?

Comment: Sorry, I'm misunderstanding you. So you want the bar to never appear no matter what the user does?

Comment: i create application for pattern lock.

Comment: But when open pattern lock screen then user click to home button activity is close. So i disable home button when activity is running.